# open facebook page in a profile form a native android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

I am using "fb://profile/xxxxxxxxxx" to open the facebook from my android app.

But the problem is, it is not opening the page in a profile. So the like, save buttons are missing. I am providing screenshots here :

**1. When opened a intent with the url.**

**2. When opened by searching within the facebook app.**

[image: opened from native app]

[image: browsing within the facebook app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fb://**page**/xxxxxxxxxx instead fb://**profile**/xxxxxxxxxx.

Though both works in ios facebook app in a similar fashion, but in android facebook app, if you use "profile" to open a page, it doesn't open properly.